# retrieving data from firebase database android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

***hello developers***

I am trying to retrieve data from Firebase but it's showing null data after applying `valueEventListener` to data, the value contained at `User` 
this is my database on firebase

[image]

this is my code

class User

```
public class User {
public String id, fname,lname, side, email, phone;


public User(){ }

public User(String id,String fname,String lname,String side, String email, String phone) {

    this.id=id;
    this.fname = fname;
    this.lname = lname;
    this.side = side;
    this.email = email;
    this.phone = phone;
}

public String getFname() {
    return fname;
}

public String getLname() {
    return lname;
}

public String getSide() {
    return side;
}

public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public String getPhone() {
    return phone;
}

public String getId() {
    return id;
}
```

my `valueEventListener`

```
String uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("users_client");
DatabaseReference userNameRef = rootRef.child(uid);
userNameRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
@Override
public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

  userinfo=dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class);
  Toast.makeText(Login.this,userinfo.getFname(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  }
   @Override
   public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
         }
  });
```

error: `java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String com.xxxx.gestient.User.getFname()' on a null object reference`

Comment: Do you want to display that particular user?

Comment: no i want to get information about this particular user

Comment: but i don't know why always i get a null user

Comment: you get null because you didn't put `child(userUid)` . you can call his userUid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting that error because you are using in your reference a wrong `uid`. When using the following line of code:

```
rootRef.child(uid);
```

You are passing to the `child(uid)` method, the user id that is coming from the authentication process. In order to be able to get user details, the key of your user object should match that `uid`. Unfortunately in your database, you aren't using that id but a key that is generated by the `push()` method, which is not correct. You have two options, one would be to remove that user and add it again using the correct `uid` or to change the above line of code to:

```
rootRef.child("-LuIC ... _9cx");
```